# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. - GRUNT

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, sails.js, bower, pipeline

My pipeline looks like this:

```
// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Dependencies like sails.io.js, jQuery, or Angular
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  'js/bower_components/angular/*.js',
  'js/bower_components/**/*.js',

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/modules/app.js',
  'js/modules/auth/services/accessLevels.js',
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```

and my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.7",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.3.7"
  }
}
```

I think this issue is because it's injecting angular.js and angular.min.js, any way to solve this with grunt?

Comment: any hard coded script tags in page?

Comment: remove 'js/bower_components/angular/*.js'.

Comment: why? If I do remove it, the scripts will be injected in no particular order and angular won't be called before my app and that will break in a million peaces.

besides, the fact that I inject a specific file (angular) and then the bower_compoents/**/*.s, it doesn't mean that angular will be called again

Comment: front bang on the file you do not want. `'!js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'` I think its the same in grunt , i have only used gulp but that is common in the globbing pattern.